# How to convert 8bit image to 16bit image depth size

Tags: drawing-tablet

I am working on android Samsung tablet so it was sport 16bit depth images. so i want to need properly convert 8dit depth to 16bit depth.

I was also trying these but when i was convert to 8bit to covert to 16bit then i was check it be 48bit

Comment: What model tablet do you have that supports 16-bit color depth?

Comment: Samsung tablet  MZ604

Comment: The MZ604, like 99.99% of all devices with LCD displays, is 32-bit Truecolor. That's 8-bits per channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're confusing bits per channel per pixel and bits per pixel.

So your "16 bit depth" tablet uses 16 bits per pixel, not 16 bits per each of the RGB channels, which would be 48 bits per pixel.

But 16 bits can't be split equally between three channels. I'd guess that two channels get 5 bits and one gets 6 bits. Think you need to confirm this.